# how to terminate qthread in python

Tags: python, pyside, qthread, terminate

I have GUI application which uses qwebview to make web automation process through long loop so I used QThread to do this but I can't terminate the thread, my code is below

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def btStart(self):
        self.mythread = BrowserThread()
        self.connect(self.mythread, SIGNAL('loop()'), self.campaign_loop, Qt.AutoConnection)
        self.mythread.start()

    def btStop(self):
        self.mythread.terminate()

    def campaign_loop(self):
        loop goes here

class BrowserThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.emit(SIGNAL('loop()'))
```

this code is working fine in starting thread but fail to stop the loop and browser still running even if I call close event to it and it disappears from GUI

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT: it works on linux too, I tried this on raspberry pi 4 and it works fine**

the point is to make the main loop in the " run " method because " terminate " function is stopping the loop in " run " not the thread its self
here is a working example for this, <del>but unfortunately it works on windows only</del>

```
import sys
import time
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class frmMain(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.btStart = QPushButton('Start')
        self.btStop = QPushButton('Stop')
        self.counter = QSpinBox()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btStart)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btStop)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.counter)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.btStart.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)
        self.btStop.clicked.connect(self.stop_thread)

    def stop_thread(self):
        self.th.stop()

    def loopfunction(self, x):
        self.counter.setValue(x)

    def start_thread(self):
        self.th = thread(2)
        #self.connect(self.th, SIGNAL('loop()'), lambda x=2: self.loopfunction(x), Qt.AutoConnection)
        self.th.loop.connect(self.loopfunction)
        self.th.setTerminationEnabled(True)
        self.th.start()

class thread(QThread):
    loop = Signal(object)

    def __init__(self, x):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.x = x

    def run(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.x = i
            self.loop.emit(self.x)
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def stop(self):
        self.terminate()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = frmMain()

win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Using self.terminate is discouraged. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27961098/4459346