# PyQt5 QThread.self.setTerminationEnabled(False) seems not to work

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

borrowing from [PySide QThread.terminate() causing fatal python error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961098/pyside-qthread-terminate-causing-fatal-python-error)  I tried this example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Looper(QtCore.QThread):
    """QThread that prints natural numbers, one by one to stdout."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Looper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.setTerminationEnabled(True)
        
        self.setTerminationEnabled(False)

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            self.msleep(100)
            print(i)
            i += 1

# Initialize and start a looper.                                                                      
looper = Looper()

looper.setTerminationEnabled(False)
looper.start()

# Sleep main thread for 5 seconds.                                                                    
QtCore.QThread.sleep(3)

# Terminate looper.                                                                                   
looper.terminate()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
app.exec_()
```

I could be wrong, but expected `looper.setTerminationEnabled(False)` or `self.setTerminationEnabled(False)` to prevent the QThread from `terminate()`
according to https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtCore/QThread.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QThread.setTerminationEnabled.

But to me it doesn't work. Any hint ??

I am using `Qt: v 5.15.2    PyQt: v 5.15.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTerminationEnabled` is a static method. It doesn't enable or disable termination of the thread it's called on, and in fact, you're not supposed to call it on a QThread instance at all.

`setTerminationEnabled` enables or disables termination of **the thread that calls `setTerminationEnabled`**. You need to call it from the `looper` thread. And no, putting it in `__init__` doesn't do that - `__init__` is not executed by the new thread. That thread hasn't even started yet. You need to call it in `run`:

```
def run(self):
    QTCore.QThread.setTerminationEnabled(False)
    ...
```

Comment: " Enables or disables termination of the current thread based on the enabled parameter. The thread must have been started by QThread . " from https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtCore/QThread.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QThread.setTerminationEnabled, I am not english native and QThreads are hard to me, but what does the quoted definition means ?

Comment: could you please write down a small piece of code based on mine illustrating your answer ,  it looks difficult to me as such, thanks

Comment: I see so I should read "The thread must have been started by QThread ." as "The thread must have been started FROM  QThread ." ???

Comment: @pippo1980: No.

Comment: I've added an example of how to call `setTerminationEnabled`.

Comment: yes thanks , I got it working , still the wording is confusing to me : " Enables or disables termination of the current thread based on the enabled parameter. The thread must have been started by QThread . "

Comment: @userw357112 so there are points to be made on 2015 post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961098/pyside-qthread-terminate-causing-fatal-python-error

Comment: @pippo1980 I believe that you're considering QThread *the* thread. That's a common misconception (valid for Python's `Tread` too). QThread doesn't represent a thread, but more like an *interface* to the system treading. We never create a thread, the OS does it, and whatever is executed in `run()` (or called from it or connected to the `started` signal) is executed in that thread. That's why `setTerminationEnabled()` is called within `run()` in the example above: because *there* it's being run in the "current thread".

Comment: @musicamante, yep thanks. I revised the meaning of static method, and then realized I was told no more than 2 days ago that the new lets call it thread  starts when QThread run method RUN runs and you are in the new thread from RUN onwards